# Can I replace lines i find with a deleted line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

if i find a line with `^//.*` this regex how do I delete the lines by putting something in the Replace with field?

e.g.  can remove all the lines that start with `//` using this regex `^//.*` and replacing with a blank line

```
// some text 
some more text 
// even more text
// even more text
// even more text
asdf
```

and the n will end up with:

```
some more text 



asdf
```

but how do I replace it with a deleted line

```
some more text 
asdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a linebreak at the end of the regex:

- Find what: `^//.*\R`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Where `\R` stands for any kind of linebreak.

NB: Do not check `. matches newline`

Comment: tks that works. does `\R` find any kind of line break and replace it with nothing?

Comment: @HattrickNZ: `\R` **matches** linebreaks, It doesn't replace anything. Have a look at: http://www.regular-expressions.info and http://pcre.org/pcre.txt

Answer (score 1):

find `^//.*\r?\n?` replace with empty, with Regular expression selected and . matches newline unselect

`\r?\n?` at the end will remove the newline as well if its there

[image: demo]

Comment: is this `\r?\n?` equivalent to `\R` in the answer above?

Comment: yes, its equivalant, `\R` will cover both `\r` and `\n`